# How to add child my view on top-level window? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I'm creating my own tabbar.
But for that, I have to attach this tabs on most high depth windows.
for example, If new navigation page is pushed on iOS, it must be on that.

How to access most top depth's layout? (I want to add child my tabs on that)

Comment: Forms doesn't have a Z index.  If multiple views are stacked on one another, the last one added will be on top.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jason . So it's hard to make my own tabs created with View base?

Comment: You can create your own tabbar but for this you will need custom renderers

Answer (score 0):

1) Make your tabbar a ContentView
2) On each of your page add the tabbar as the last child of your Content (being an AbsoluteLayout for example)

Comment: Yes I can do that. but It's totally different with built in tabbar. When new page is pushed there should be another tabbar if I use this way.